# Want to vectorise a function in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a function in Python which I want to convert it into R-function and use vectorisation. But I am not able to do it.

This is my python function

```
import random as rd
N_population = 1000
first_sick = 2
status = [0] * N_population
day_count = [0] * N_population
index = rd.sample(range(N_population), first_sick)
for i in index:
    status[i] = 1
    day_count[i] = 1
# find sick people
def find_sick(status):
    index = []
    for i in range(N_population):
        if status[i] == 1:
            # sick
            index.append(i)
    return(index)
```

Comment: OK, what have you tried?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for the R functions `rep`, `sample` and `which`, and see if you can figure something out from that.